# Request for mod action against a user making lots of harmful backticking edits

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

This user:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4675055/gouda-elalfy

has been making lots of harmful edits that backtick random words or technology names. Disappointingly but unsurprisingly to anyone familiar with the Suggested Edits queue, most of these edits have been approved, mostly by the owners of the edited posts (who were usually new users who didn't know any better) but sometimes by folks in the review queue.

On a less important note, he also frequently "fixes" users who've written single literal newlines in their markdown that don't get rendered by adding in `<br>` tags, when it would be better for him to add an additional newline to create a proper paragraph break.

List of edits that backtick things inappropriately, but also do something at least slightly worthwhile (including backticking other things *appropriately*):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10705408
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10704469
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664080
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664031
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10653937
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10652153
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10650655
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10650626
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10627244
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10627240
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10622904
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10622764
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10594938
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10589302
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10575169
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10570664
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10567575
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10566094
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10560999
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10556621
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10552762
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10552018
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10514075
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10663861

List of edits that backtick thing inappropriately, and are otherwise completely worthless or outright harmful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10704522
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10704261
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10665280
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664186
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10654543
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10649914
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10620338
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10614591
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10560115

List of edits that add `<br>`s inappropriately:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10704406
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10704297
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10696465
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10666530
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10665105
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664019

Other egregiously bad suggestions with no redeeming qualities by the same user:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10664688 (marks up random paragraphs as quotes)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10654785 (more arbitrary use of quote blocks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10654283 (more arbitrary use of quote blocks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10653779 (marks up a random paragraph as a quote; removes quote marks around an *actual* quote)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10652237 (replaces correct spelling "subdomain" with incorrect spelling "sub domain")
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10652045 (replaces some confusing and unclear writing with... complete nonsense)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10651956 (arbitrary, pointless formatting changes including an inappropriate quote block)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10565698 (deleted the only paragraph of explanatory prose from the question and did nothing else, with edit summary "format the code")

Other suggestions by the same user that do some good but also do some harm:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10662925 (changed "mysql database" to "mysqli database" in question title; a "mysqli database" isn't a thing and the question isn't using MySQLi)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10655333 (improper use of quote blocks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10654724 (improper use of quote blocks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10650645 (reintroduced 'somebody please help me' to the end of the question)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10627279 (introduces inconsistency on whether to backtick *"`td`"*)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10627064 (**arbitrary** use **of** bold text all **over the place**)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10598720 (arbitrary use of quote block)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10553669 (replaces defined variable `$dataid` with undefined variable `$memberid` inside a code block)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10553478 (introduces absurd spelling error in the first edited word)

<strike>I'm about to go</strike> I have gone on a massive editing spree reverting all the bad things from every single edit listed above, but I'd like a mod to message the user and:

1. Ask him to stop backticking things other than code or the things on the list at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/1709587. In particular, make clear that backticks should not be used for emphasis, nor for technology names like "Syfony" or "PHP".
2. Ask him to use proper paragraph breaks instead of `<br>`s when editing paragraph breaks into posts. i.e. instead of writing markdown like this:

   ```
   Bla bla bla one paragraph<br>
   La la la another paragraph
   ```

   ... he should instead write markdown like this, which results in both prettier markdown and a prettier rendered result:

   ```
   Bla bla bla one paragraph

   La la la another paragraph
   ```
3. Ask him to use proper edit summaries. Many of his edit summaries are completely unrelated to the changes that he's made, like [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10652614) which purely fixes grammar and punctuation errors but has the edit summary *"highlight your important words"*
4. Ask him to only use quote blocks for:

   - quotes
   - error messages or log output (unless they look better in a code block)
5. Link him to this Meta post

I'd *also* suggest that a mod review-bans every single one of the 10 non-OP users who voted to approve any of the suggestions I've listed under *"edits that backtick thing inappropriately, and are otherwise completely worthless or outright harmful"* or *"Other egregiously bad suggestions"*, although that's up to the mods. I won't provide a list here since I figure the mods will need to confirm I haven't screwed it up anyway. You might even want to message anyone who voted to approve anything in any of the lists above. Really, this is exactly the kind of situation where I want to be able [to message these reviewers myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers) rather than having to leave that to the moderators, but I can't.

Aside: is there a better way to handle this kind of bullshit in future? I'm not a fan of public shaming and as such I don't particularly like publicly linking to users that I want punished, especially over something of pretty much zero moral importance like this. I would prefer this matter be purely between the problematic users and the mods, but without a private message feature (besides the flagging dialog with its highly restrictive character limit) I don't know what else to do but post here.

Comment: I put him 7 days off suggested edits without looking at any of the other links. Then scrolled down to make this comment.

Comment: @BoltClock it'd be helpful to communicate to him my points about what not to do in future, or else we may have more of the same in 7 days' time.

Comment: Whoah...respect for the research effort, and for the ensuing edit spree.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It felt worth doing. Most of the fixes I applied weren't that important in terms of actual impact on post quality, but crucially, most of the affected posts were from newbies and bad edits to newbie posts really piss me off. There's a high risk that we either teach harmful practices to our newbies, or, if they're bright enough to see that the edits are stupid, put potentially good contributors off the site and make our whole community look like fools. I care much more about reverting a bad edit made to somebody's post than I would about making the same edit in other circumstances.

Comment: I fully agree, and it's heartbreaking to see this amount of work put into such crappy edits. Our editor has worked a lot on this, and he could've added valuable contributions to the site with the same work. But regardless, I wouldn't have had the patience to track even a fraction of his work:)

Comment: Reminder that you can leave a comment on any post where a bad edit has been *approved* which will notify the editor if you include an @-ping. So you don't need to wait for moderator intervention to offer guidance; if it isn't followed, then it becomes necessary.

Comment: @Shog9 Honestly, there are no circumstances in which I'd rather do that than go straight to a mod flag. Doing things that way, I'm creating comment noise, I'm dependent upon him noticing the notification (I've observed multiple colleagues who are light Stack Exchange users who don't even realise the inbox exists), I have to remember to monitor the comment thread for replies (since the people who screw up edits this badly will probably also screw up @-notifications), and if the user *does* reply, I'm going to end up making mods spend time on it anyway when I flag the comments as obsolete.

Comment: @Shog9 I might @-notify a user *in addition* to raising a mod flag if they were editing extremely rapidly at right that moment and I wanted to try to dampen the fires before a moderator could take firmer action, but the mod flag is always going to be my primary way of addressing these people because the alternative is more work for no advantage that I can see.

Comment: The problem is, if you don't say anything then you're depending on the user figuring it out themselves; edit-blocks are mostly silent. So in 7 days, you might well have this problem again... If someone isn't checking their inbox, they won't see a moderator message either.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, I didn't know that. I assumed this user would've been private-messaged in some way by the mods with either a link to this post or a summary of what I'd written here, and also assumed that moderator messages were more aggressively presented to users than mere comments to make sure that they aren't missed. I guess I'll go and find a particularly low-viewed, low-value post that he's edited and create some comment noise. :/

Comment: I got this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369040/phusion-passenger-activerecordpendingmigrationerror#comment56746355_34369040

Comment: Related: [How can we stop crazy edits like this from being accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313480/how-can-we-stop-crazy-edits-like-this-from-being-accepted)

Comment: thanks @MarkAmery for your efforts, but firstly you should guide me. you also didn't tell me about all of this.

Comment: @BoltClock there is no way to tell me why you put me off? I will not see this post If Shog9 guide me. How I know my fault without Shog9?

Comment: Thank you very much @Shog9

Comment: @MarkAmery http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10650645 this post already has this missed text. I didn't add it, but there is something hide it from the question. and in such cases the question owner can refuse it.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy: "in such cases the question owner can refuse it."  Lots of owners don't know English very well, and accept edits in hope that the person editing knows better English then them.  In addition, there is never a reason that "somebody please help me" should be added.  Lastly, if you were trying to fix any grammar errors in the edit, you missed.  I still count three grammar errors in the post.  An edit shouldn't always fix everything, but you should try to get most things, especially if they are easy.

Comment: This is Justice. We don't users like this harming this community. Ban them!

Comment: "Aside: is there a better way to handle this kind of bullshit in future". Yes. This bullshit would immediately go away forever if we stopped giving rep for suggested edits. The only reason anyone ever makes these garbage-quality backticks edits is when rep farming. And, permanently ban any of the incompetent reviewers who approved these edits.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I mentioned this in comments already, but worth elaborating on it a bit... **The most immediate way to stop a bad editor is to educate them in the context of a bad edit.** There are two convenient ways to do this:

1. **Reject the edit.** If there are bad edits still pending review *and* you reject them, [the editor will be warned the next time he goes to edit.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334) Don't forget, you can single-handedly reject any pending edit by choosing "Reject and Edit" and submitting a different (hopefully exemplary) edit to the post.
2. **Leave a comment on a post that was edited.** A little-known feature of [comment @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) is that you can notify anyone who has ever edited a post in a comment on that post by prefixing their name with @. Use this - along with judicious edits or rollbacks - to inform editors of problematic behaviors, and guide them away from trouble.

You can *also* flag for moderator attention if need-be, but please consider first offering some guidance to the editor yourself; the only *additional* option available to moderators is the formal "contact user" system, which sends a private message and is reserved for extremely serious behavioral problems.

Comment: "you can single-handedly reject any pending edit by choosing "Reject and Edit"" sadly this [doesn't count towards edits bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/213575), so no message is shown.

Comment: Did you read the answer you linked to, @Braiam? *"As of September 2014 these do count toward edit bans (and warnings)..."*

Comment: Oh, I read it backwards... shame on me. Now I see that I have a new toy... lets play with it >:D

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that the worst-case offenders find the edit ban the most instructive channel of communication:)

Comment: Thank you very much @Shog9, you are the only one told me about all of this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sigh, the lead by example answer. Replace the faulty edits with good edits and invest time and effort yourself rather than immediately defaulting to flagging stuff you don't like. Okay okay, upvoted it *dad*.

Comment: @Shog9 Once I read something about opening a chat with the user to notify him in an educational manner... Is it really possible? If so: How would I do that? Is there a reason for not mentioning it as an option in your answer?

Comment: That's a LOT of overhead for what should normally be a fairly brief exchange, @falsearella.

Comment: @falsarella AFAIK you must go to chat and search for the user, then click "start a new room with this user."

Comment: Aha... Because the @nameOfEditors is not typed automatically, I did not know I can use their names, too. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still see a lot of such edits in the review queue, from various users. Some even only add **bold**. I accept some extra backtick where it was clearly only done to reach the 6 characters, but otherwise these get very annoying. I don't feel I have enough energy to educate all those users right now. :)

Comment: Just remember that YOU aren't subject to the 6-character limit, @Nemo. So you can always reject and edit if the change is harmful, or simply to demonstrate a more productive way of revising the post.

Answer (score 24):

> is there a better way to handle this kind of bullshit in future? I'm
>   not a fan of public shaming and as such I don't particularly like
>   publicly linking to users that I want punished

[Looks like BoltClock has already taken care of this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313517/request-for-mod-action-against-a-user-making-lots-of-harmful-backticking-edits#comment287633_313517), but in the future you can probably just drop a custom moderator attention flag on one of the user's post describing the situation.

Something like:

> This user seems to be suggesting an awful lot of bad edits, they may
>   need some guidance or a temporary edit suspension. See:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

It may be worthwhile to add a couple links to the worst suggested edits as well, just to be clear about what the problem is.

Comment: I enjoy how you used a link to *my* profile in your example flag message calling for a user to be suspended. Cheeky bastard.

Comment: @MarkAmery All names have been changed to protect the... errr... guilty...

Comment: Anyway - usually I do just flag over bad edit suggesters. As for why I didn't just do this in this case: I wanted to go through all the user's edits anyway in order to revert the bad ones, and I wanted to flag up reviewers for suspension and provide a full list of the problematic types of edits the user was making in order that they could be properly communicated to the user. I couldn't've fit all that into a flag. It's one thing when you're dealing with dozens of edits with a single recurring problem, but when it's hundreds with a huge variety of different problems, more action is needed.

Comment: @MarkAmery The effort is admirable, but I would assume the moderators would normally sift through, at least some if not most, of a problematic user's suggestions in a case like this.

Comment: @MarkAmery I've seen at least a couple cases where they even made a point to pass out some review suspensions while they were at it. Obviously I can't speak for them, but I would think that these kinds of flags are often just the tip of the ice-berg.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just raise a custom flag as apaul34208 suggested. One or two examples would be helpful, but please don't feel like you need to collect as many examples as @MarkAmery did.

Comment: @MarkAmery Please note that you don't generally need to undo all of the bad edits. If the edit *breaks* something, okay. If it's just bad/inefficient/ugly markdown, don't worry about it. Thanks for the effort to fix things up, though!

Comment: You can also use a deleted answer of your own as a convenient staging ground for long link lists that don't fit into a normal flag, then flag that post with a custom message that explains what you want the mod to do with that stuff.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Better a deleted question. Or a deleted answer on a deleted question.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Deleted questions cannot be edited, if memory serves, but a deleted answer on a deleted question is fine.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Yes, self-deleted questions need not apply...