# How to notify users, when their edits are rolled back?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

Sometimes, edits go terribly wrong. This isn't too troublesome, as long as your edits are peer-reviewed. Once you earn the [Edit Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege, however, your edits are no longer scrutinized, nor do you get *any* feedback on their quality.

It so happened, that I came across the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51497920/1889329)<sup>1</sup>:

> I am new to win32. In C# it is possible to have a form semi-transparent but not control (using hatch brush). Any guidance, how to achieve this in win-32 window. Thanks in advance.

It was edited (well, butchered) into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51497920/2):

> In C#, is it possible to have a form semi-transparent but not control it using hatch brush in Win32?

That edit was actively harmful, substantially changing the question that was asked<sup>2</sup>. I rolled back the edit<sup>3</sup>, but it doesn't appear to be possible to let the user know, that they have done a poor job.

Is there any way to get the information across, before more harm is done? Would it be a good idea to automatically send a message to users, when their edits get rolled back?

---

<sup>1</sup> *It's a poor question to begin with. But this post is not about the question quality. It is about the quality of the edit.*

<sup>2</sup> *The edit changed the meaning in the following ways: `1` It turned a statement, meant as an example, into a question ("In C# it is possible..." to "In C#, is it possible...?"). `2` It changed the meaning of "control" from (what I assume to be) a noun to a verb. `3` It simply appended the remainder of the question to its newly invented question, rendering it meaningless ("In C#, is it possible to have ... in Win32?").*

<sup>3</sup> *I wasn't sure how to expand on the initial edit, while retaining the author's intent. I'm not even entirely sure, what the question is asking for. Rolling back the entire edit and giving the OP a chance to clarify appeared to be the only non-destructive option.*

Comment: I recommend reading Shog's answer... is eye opening!

Comment: @Braiam: The edit didn't change the question into a similar, more interesting question. The edit changed the question into a **question that doesn't even make sense**. This, unfortunately, is not at all a duplicate. It's not even close...

Comment: I don't care if the question changed or not... nobody has ever bothered to communicate to the author to figure out what it is(n't) asking. That's why my recommendation, I suggest you to follow it.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm not sure, why you are directing the suggesting towards me. I didn't make any changes the author didn't agree with, right? I rolled back those changes, the author certainly wouldn't have agreed with.

Comment: @user202729: If you don't understand a question, don't attempt to modify it. Ask for clarification, instead of doing an edit based on unfounded assumptions. If reviewers would have made the same mistake, then maybe those reviewers should have hit the *"Skip"* button instead. I'm not sure how any of that is relevant, though. A user made an edit that was clearly harmful, and I asked how to get feedback to them, to be more careful next time around.

Comment: @IInspectable "can you please edit the information about what is wrong with the edit to the question itself?"

Comment: You can @ mention an editor in a comment to the edited question, can't you?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I'm not sure. The user name didn't show up as a tooltip after typing `@` into the comment field, like it usually would.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't show up there, but if you enter it in manually, it does notify them. I've used it in the past when I've noticed a user doing a bunch of harmful edits to see if I can get them to stop before bringing in the moderators.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Ok, thank you. So this is really just a combination of a poor UI and lacking documentation. Would be nice to know, which users you can ping using the `@`-trigger, either through better documentation or a better UI.

Comment: Sure. There are a few questions about the @ mention on Meta SO (I think I learned it from [Request for mod action against a user making lots of harmful backticking edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313553), it's also on Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020), and it is mentioned briefly in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Heretic Monkey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey):

> You can @ mention an editor in a comment to the edited question...Yeah
>   it doesn't show up [as a tooltip], but if you enter it in manually, it
>   does notify them. I've used it in the past when I've noticed a user
>   doing a bunch of harmful edits to see if I can get them to stop before
>   bringing in the moderators.

As for automatically notifying a user if an edit gets rolled back, I think this could cause other problems:

- You can go back several revisions when you rollback. You don't necessarily want to ping every editor between revision [n] and revision [n-4], nor do you necessarily want to ping the last editor.
- It could encourage rollback wars. When a user disagrees with a suggested edit getting rejected, they'd either have to take it to meta or re-submit the edit.  Without a good explanation for why the initial rollback happened, a 2K+ rep user may just rollback the rollback.
  I don't think a generic message would work, at least not in cases like this.

I think it would be enough to just make it clearer that editors can be pinged.

Answer (score 8):

All of the information removed in that edit was noise. Removing it was beneficial.  After a few reads, it looks like the editor also misunderstood the (very unclear and poorly phrased) original question and in an attempt to make it clearer, they made what they thought was an aesthetic change that actually changed meaning.

When someone makes an inappropriate edit you can comment on the post to reply to them, if you want to discuss it with them.  I've re-applied the parts of the edit that were beneficial, while adjusting the parts of the question that you have identified as being improperly handled.  Since the original was...pretty bad, I didn't just roll back to the original wording, I *worked to provide a clearer wording of the original intent*, and replied to you stating as much to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Er... what? The edit changed a statement into a question, and then moved on to ask the wrong question. The OP never asked, how to do something in C#. They wanted to do it in native code, yet the edit suggested the opposite. The term *"control"* meant *"user control"* in the OP, after the edit it was turned into a verb. That edit was just wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable:  Am I missing something since I arrived at the same conclusion as Servy?  Of concern is where they explicitly call out C#.  If they wanted to do this natively, then you should ask a clarifying comment to be sure of that fact.  Assuming is *dangerous*.

Comment: @Makoto: I'm not assuming. I know. That might be, because I also know the problem domain. From your profile, it doesn't appear that you do.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, I see what you're getting at now.  In that case, you should have corrected the *one* mistake with the edit, in which they combined a statement and a question instead of leaving them separate, *without rolling back the useful edits that removed noise*.

Comment: @Makoto It took me a couple reads, but it _looks_ like the original question was only using C# as an example of what they wanted to do. But, again, it took a couple read throughs to catch that myself.

Comment: @IInspectable:  I confess; I'm woefully ignorant of development in C# and on Windows.   I can at least be led, however, from context clues and clear information made apparent to me in a question.  No such context?  No reason to guess.  It's a bitter pill to swallow since I did the ***exact same thing*** as you did yesterday (and Bohemian can attest to this better than I can), but assuming context in a question is a dangerous path.

Comment: @Makoto So after a few reads, it looks like the original quest was asking (poorly), "I can do X in C#, can I also do X in Win32?" and the question was edited to, "How can I do X in C# using Win32?", which is a different question.

Comment: @Makoto: Here is a clue, that doesn't need any domain-specific knowledge: Changing *"In C#, it is possible..."* into *"In C#, is it possible...?"* substantially changes the intent. That's another point the editor got wrong. The editor got **everything** wrong here.

Comment: @Servy:  Fair enough.  I could see the easy mistake in editing there, and I do agree that rolling it *all* back was not the right choice there.

Comment: @IInspectable:  We have to rely on subject matter experts like yourself to identify situations like this and make the right corrections.  Rolling back everything wasn't the right correction.

Comment: @Makoto: It *was* the right correction, until the OP would have come back to clarify. Since the question is poor, I didn't bother asking for clarification. It's unfortunate, that while I clearly identified an edit, that actively harmed the question, everyone is attacking *my* actions. The user who actively harmed this site is not ever mentioned, nor are my questions being addressed. Oh well, such is meta, I guess.

Comment: @IInspectable Someone edited a question to make it substantially better, but made one minor mistake in the process.  You decided to, rather than fixing that one problem, to introduce half a dozen additional problems.  That's not appropriate.  Had you just fixed the one problem you saw that would have been fine.  People make mistakes from time to time when editing.  It happens.

Comment: @Servy: They didn't make *"one minor mistake"*. They made **several** **severe** mistakes. Like changing a statement into a question, changing the word *"control"* (noun) into the word *"control"* (verb), finishing it all up in a question, that doesn't make sense: *"In C#, is it possible <blah> in Win32?"* May I suggest that you leave this to the subject matter experts to discuss?

Comment: @IInspectable, there are 2 subject matters being discussed here: a programming one and an editorial one, you seem to be failing to grasp the later, please check: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edits?sort=frequent **and** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edits?sort=frequent

Comment: @brasofilo: Correct. And I wasn't asking about either. Both answerers based their answers on the assumption, that the initial edit *didn't* change the intent of the question, finding great comfort in agreeing with each other, only to later realize, that the edit *was* indeed harmful. Rolling it back to let the OP clarify was the only option, as I'm not even sure, what they were asking for. Servy, on the other hand, based their edit on the *assumption*, that they knew what was being asked. That assumption is unfounded, hence the second roll-back.

Comment: @IInspectable They didn't properly understand the intended meaning of an extremely poorly written post with lots of various mistakes.  They did their best to determine what it was actually trying to ask and didn't realize exactly what the various mistakes in the original post were.  You had the oppertunity to correct thier mistake and improve the post.  You choose not to, and just introduced a whole bunch of major problems back into the post.  Then, when the post was fixed, you reverted it *again*, even though there was no mistake, introducing *only* errors into a post, for no reason.

Comment: @IInspectable If you're not even sure what the OP was asking for *then you can't even assert that the edit was incorrect*.  You could only make such an assertion if you actually think you know what the post was asking.  I also note that what I interpreted the question as asking *is exactly what you've asserted the question is asking*, so you're accusing me of making an incorrect assumption *that you yourself have made, and used as the sole reasoning for your rollback of the post*.

Comment: You can determine, that an edit changed the meaning of a question, even if you don't fully understand the question. I have established that in a previous comment to this proposed answer. Not being sure, what the author is asking for exactly can still allow me to know, that your edit changed the meaning. After all, [I understand the problem domain](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1421/winapi) much better than you do.

Comment: @IInspectable How did my edit change the meaning of the post?  If you don't know what the meaning is, how do you know that it's different?

Comment: I have made it previously clear, that that line of reasoning is ever so flawed. If you absolutely *must* have the last word on this, be my guest. I'm out of this. A user has answered my question. That's all I ever asked for.

Comment: @IInspectable That you can't say anything about how my edit changed the meaning of the post says a lot.  If you are unable to state how the meaning was changed, you can't assert that the meaning was changed.  As for the other answer, it's just re-stating what was already in this answer, so you got what you asked for right from the start.