# Reject edit because it introduces complex code and might make the answer more confusing?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

There is a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10827587) to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791632/1986871).

The edit introduces code which, according to the editor, explains my previous edit (#3); however, it looks cryptic and I can't verify its validity.

The **Reject** dialog placeholder text is "*Describe how this edit would make the post worse.*" - I don't *think* the edit would make the post worse, but it might, and I can't tell one way or the other - the only thing I'm positive of is that the editor's intent is good. They're trying to make the post more informative, but their edit adds complexity.

Should I reject the edit? And if so, what reject reason should I choose?

This is the first time I've had a suggested edit on one of my answers.

Comment: If you don't feel confident in the code's correctness, or you just don't know period, sounds like a good reason to reject to me. I personally wouldn't want someone putting their code that I haven't tested under my name.

Comment: hmm... to your own answer... If you don't know what it does, probably shouldn't accept it. I would leave the message "I don't know what this code does, please leave a comment instead.". I would reject an edit like that if i was reviewing edits to other posts that weren't my own, it's enough content to merit a separate answer.

Comment: Actually, looking at it, that looks like a major change to your answer and putting a lot of words in your mouth. That alone would make _me_ reject for "changes author's intent."

Comment: I rejected it as "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."  It was so extensive that it should have been a new answer instead.

Comment: two people actually approved it..

Comment: @KevinB grab the meta-pitchforks!

Comment: The guy could write his own answer with the proposed content...

Comment: @Trilarion That's exactly what he ended up doing

Comment: "Describe how this edit would make the post worse." Answer: "By introducing confusing code."

Comment: Related: [How can we stop crazy edits like this from being accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313480/3899908)

Comment: @KevinB and that's a surprise because why? roboreview ftw

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A ***lot*** of red flags came up for me.  Here's why:

- There's a *lot* of new information
- It's being added in as if you had said it
- You *yourself* said that you didn't know if it worked

To be blunt, the third reason would be *enough* to reject it, but from an outsider's standpoint, 1 and 2 are good reasons to reject it outright.

If they want to add that information, it should be in a separate answer, and not in yours.

Comment: I'm going to reject and leave a comment for the editor to post it as a new answer with a link to my answer for context. He said that he had successfully ported the code to Python for use in a similar project that implements Google TTS, so it seems legitimate. It just doesn't belong in my answer :) thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice well, we the community already rejected it...

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah I see that now haha. The Meta Effect in play. That's alright, community rejecting or me, it's done!

Comment: All turned out well in the end. However, I simply cannot believe that two reviewers accepted the suggested edit. OK, so I *can*, but...

Answer (score 20):

If this happened to me, I would reject it because I can't verify that it makes my answer better.

If I came across it in the suggested edit queue, I would reject it as an attempt to answer the question or address the author, that much information should instead be included in a separate answer.

Comment: Yep.  Approving code changes and the like means taking responsibility for the content and its accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think edits should be used for code changes, unless it is a very obvious syntactical mistake.