# Why was the third edit in this question approved?

Tags: discussion, edits

Why was revision #3 approved for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34684751/revisions

[image]

This change is to the actual code and is more than simple formatting.  It actually alters the code and is not what the OP has posted.  I would assume that any such alternations to the original code is frowned upon as the behavior is being tested on what the OP has provided and not what someone might presume it should have been instead.

Comment: OP approved it http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10828131

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with that argument in the comments on the question regarding the OP's code examples not actually working.

Comment: Related: [How can we stop crazy edits like this from being accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313480/how-can-we-stop-crazy-edits-like-this-from-being-accepted)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the suggesting info shows that the OP approved the edit that was suggested by an anonymous user: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10828131

*Why* they approved it is a good question, as is why two previous reviewers voted to approve it.

Comment: Ah, good catch.  I missed the OP approval part.  I am baffled by the approval of two other reviewers, as you've noted, though.

Answer (score 8):

The OP was not asking "why does this code not work".  The OP was trying to give examples of two different operations.

The code given did not work.  This was clearly not what the OP was asking about.  Fixing them to they are what the OP was asking about, instead of non-compiling code, is a good edit.

Determining what the OP really was asking about, and that the prior code failed, and that the new code succeeded, with high accuracy isn't always easy, but in this case it appears to be.

Comment: But if the code is altered in those two different operations, then it changes what is being compared.  If OP did not know the proper formulation of the code that he's trying to compare, then it's a whole different issue and could be one of the problems in his comparison.  Thus, it should be provided as an answer or a comment, not a direct edit.

Comment: @b.k. the old code contained (obvious to a programmer in the language) obvious typos.  Fixing typos is something that can be done *without* the input of the OP, *if* the typos are not central to the problem at hand.  And the comments indicate they where not.